# Node.js stucked with var declaration

Tags: node.js, express

I have encode\decode up (React Next.sjs + Node.js Express). I've done almost everything I wanted. The only one problem I don't know how to solve this is decoding. For decoding\encoding I'm using `Cryptr` library.

Here below my decode function code:

```
export const decodeBlog = async(req, res, next) => {
    const { text, secretkeyword } = req.body;
    const cryptr = new Cryptr(secretkeyword);
    const encrypted = text;
    let decrypted;   //The problem is here
    try {
        const decrypted = cryptr.decrypt(encrypted, secretkeyword);
        console.log("encrypted data", decrypted);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({message: "Incorrect Secret keyword"});
    }
    return res.status(200).json({message: decrypted}); 
};
```

[image]

Here in postman I'm getting an empty {} brackets.

But in node.js console I have console.log and it works:

[image]

I will be really appreciate if you help me. Thank you in advance!:)

Comment: Are you passing the body content in Postman ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *two* variables named `decrypted`:

- one inside the try-catch block: this one is declared with `const`, it gets a value and is output with `console.log`
- one outside the try-catch block: this one is declared with `let` and output with `res.json`, but it never gets a value.

Omit the word `const` inside the try-catch block. The `let` outside suffices.